# recursively unzip filenames with spaces in linux and save log

Tags: linux, ssh

I used >>
logsave path/log.txt find . -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'unzip -l {} | head -n 7' \; to get the list of files inside zip files in a particular folder. Here is a problem if the filename contains one or more spaces it is just skipping the files.  Dir structure is

---

### Dir..

### ..........File1.zip  **without space in name

### ...........Fi le2.zip  **With space in name

### ...........F i l e 3.zip  **with spaces in name

For above case file names in file1.zip is listed only.  Can anyone recommend a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enclosing your zip filenames in quotes so that unzip knows it is only one file name:

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'unzip -l "{}" | head -n 7' \;
```

The reason that we need to quote the {} in the above command is that we are passing a string to sh to run as a command line.

I will try to explain what is happening step by step:

For each file that matches *.zip, we will run the command `sh -c 'unzip -l "{}" | head -n 7`. 
`sh -c 'blahblablah'` takes the argument after -c and runs it as if it was entered on the command line.

So given a filename `File A.zip` (with a space) we will execute the command line:

```
unzip -l File A.zip | head -n 7
```

Now, what happens when we don't quote the filename is that before calling unzip, the shell will split the argument list into separate arguments, resulting in a list:

```
"unzip" "-l" "File" "A.zip"
```

which means that `unzip` will try to open the zip file `File` and look for the item `A.zip` inside the archive.

If we enclose the argument in quotes the shell will expand to the following argument list:

```
"unzip" "-l" "File A.zip"
```

Win! `unzip` will now try to open the zip file "File A.zip" and list its contents.

Comment: thanks.. A simple but effective change. can you please explain how quote is used to ignore spaces.

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and explain why the quotes are needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it with **for** too.

`for file in *.zip; do unzip -l "$file" | head -n 7; done`

Comment: interesting! I first thought this wouldn't work because it would be the same as "for file in $(ls *zip) .... but then I tried and it actually works, even though i dont exactly understand why/how... some detail of shell wildcard handling that i do not yet understand ;) thanks!

Comment: Don't need to use **$(ls \*.zip)** - in fact, it can be a little bit messy if the filenames contains spaces (try it). 
The correct way to tell shell script that you need to get a file list is using the wildcard **\***. You can try it with subdirs too, like "**for file in /dir/subdir/*.zip; do echo $file; done**" :)

Comment: I tried it and it worked and that was why I said thanks ;)